# ASP.Net - Input String not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to implement a functionality whereby if I click a button it adds a new unit to a module (basically a new page), but am getting error on the below line:

```
UnitID = Request["UnitID"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Request["UnitID"]) : 0;
```

And the stacktrace is

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number,    NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +7470855
System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
System.Convert.ToInt32(String value) +63
Data_Project.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in       
C:\Projects\Projects.aspx.cs:69
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, 
Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Can you please tell me what the error is?

Many advance thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the content of Request["UnitID"]? Maybe it is not a number.

Comment: Don't take this as a slight, but if you don't learn how to read exception messages like this, you're in for a long and frustrating career.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have something in `Request["UnitID"]` which is not a number

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you will want to try

```
int UnitID = 0;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["UnitID"]))
{
    UnitID = 0;
}
else
{
    if(!Int32.TryParse(Request["UnitID"], out UnitID))
    {
        UnitID = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The error "Input String not in a correct format" means that Request["UnitID"] can't be converted to an integer.

Try This:

```
UnitID = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["UnitID"]) ? Convert.ToInt32(Request["UnitID"]) : 0;
```

Or this:

```
if(!int.TryParse(Request["UnitID"]+"", out UnitID)
{
UnitID = 0;
}
```